# AVAudioPlayer in not playing file from url?

Tags: ios4, avaudioplayer

I am trying to play a recorded file in AVAudioPlayer.
It plays my Local recording fine but when I try to play the same file stored on server with a valid url it doesn't play any sound..?

I tried

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.filePathUrl];
NSData *memoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:memoData error:nil];//[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error: nil];
```

This is not working..

I am not understanding what happen while getting data from url. I am getting my data too. its length is not 0. and the file format on server is .caf only. Please help me to understand the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it return an error when u use a NSError object instead of nil?

Comment: you can follow the link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605846/avaudioplayer-with-external-url-to-m4p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to start the audioplayer

```
  [newPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 3):

The AVAudioPlayer can only play local files. See [the Apple Developer page on AVAudioPlayer streaming support](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2009/qa1634.html).

You could use [Miguel's streaming audio player](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/StreamingAudio) that uses an AudioQueue but I don't think you can seek or scrub the audio.

Hope this helps.