# how to play binarydata of song in AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm receiving songs url from xml and saving them in sqlite as binary data.
Now I want to play those songs in AVAudioPlayer.

How would I achieve this?
Is this method is right for playing binarydata of song in AVAudioPlayer.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this post:

[AVAudioPlayer with external URL to *.m4p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605846/avaudioplayer-with-external-url-to-m4p)

AVAudioPlayer only works with local URL's. It must be a File URL (file://)

See [Apple's Technical Q&A QA1634](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2009/qa1634.html)

You could get your binary data and write it to a file and then play it:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a825.phobos.apple.com/us/r2000/005/Music/d8/a8/d2/mzi.jelhjoev.aac.p.m4p"]; 
NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] 
                                                stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];
[soundData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL
                                fileURLWithPath:filePath] error:NULL];  
NSLog(@"error %@", error);
```