# AVAudioplayer not playing song from iPod library in iOS 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, avaudioplayer, playback

I am creating an iPhone application using AVAudioPlayer. It is working fine in iOs 6 devices. But it is not playing song from iPod library in iOs 5 and lower versions. When I tried to play a music file from NSBundle it is working, so the issue is only when I try to play the song from iPod library. Here is my code, please check

```
if (isPlaying) {
    [audioPlayer stop];
    isPlaying = NO;
}

extern NSMutableArray *songsUrlArray;
extern int selectedSongIndex;

audioPlayer.volume = 1.0;

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[songsUrlArray objectAtIndex:selectedSongIndex]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

    if (audioPlayer == nil)
        NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
    else{
        [audioPlayer play];
    isPlaying = YES;
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is the error message that I got,

```
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-43 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)"
```

When I googled, I found that `OSStatus error -43` is getting when there is no contents available in the specified path. Here is the path to a song from iPod library in the 3GS device, `ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=564371652689620079`. But its not playing. Please some
Please help

Comment: Please check this link,it may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605846/avaudioplayer-with-external-url-to-m4p

Comment: I am not trying to play song from a url, i want to play the song from the ipod library.

Comment: @Mithuzz did you ever figure this out? I'm getting the exact same error trying to play a song from the library. Only happens on ios5.

Answer (score 0):

AVAudioPlayer only gained support for iPod URLs in iOS6. You'll have to use AVPlayer or AVQueuePlayer if you want to support target pre-iOS6 devices.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS6.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011812-SW1