# Why do I unwrap nil in my Swift file?

Tags: json, swift, audio, avfoundation, itunes

I have an app (the same one from my previous post about unwrapping `nil`. I really hate `nil` now.) that searches the iTunes store and returns data in JSON. I have it working, it gets the song name, artist name, everything! I created an `@IBAction` button for playing the song's preview. The JSON has a property that is the url to the song preview. When I click the button, it does the following:

```
        let alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(url, ofType: "m4a")!)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
        var error:NSError?
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
```

The `url` is this: `http://a1993.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/101/Music/b7/b3/e0/mzm.ooahqslp.aac.p.m4a`. I know my setup for playing an audio file works; I have another app I am building that uses the exact same setup. Why does it tell me that I unwrap `nil` here: `http://a1993.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/101/Music/b7/b3/e0/mzm.ooahqslp.aac.p.m4a`? The url is valid and the file plays.

Answer (score 0):

Examine this line of code.

```
let alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(url, ofType: "m4a")!)
```

`fileUrlWithPath` is asking for a local path, that is one on your device.

`NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(url.....`

This method returns the local path for the resource you send to it.  You are sending it a web url, which is not in the mainBundle unless you've explicitly put it there.  So the path that it returns is nil, because there is no local path that satisfies the arguments you are passing to it.

Comment: How can I make it to where it does a file on the web?

Comment: Use the unedited path you get from the JSON (maybe you post what it contains as example)

Comment: the url is `http://a1993.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/101/Music/b7/b3/e0/mzm.ooahqslp.aac.p.m4a` and just play the file with `audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfUrl: url, error &error)`?

Comment: I don't think AVAudioPLayer will let you play streamed files directly, at least simply.  Your likely best next step is just to download the audio to a file, and then play that.  See this (objective c based) answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605846/avaudioplayer-with-external-url-to-m4p

Answer (score 0):

If you have a local resource you should use a method called URLForResource

This line makes no sense. You should always prefer working with urls and extract the path from it if needed.

Replace this line:

```
let alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("fileName", ofType: "m4a")!)  // this would crash if not found (nil)
```

with this block of code

```
if let alertSoundUrl =  NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("fileName", withExtension: "m4a") {
    println(true)
} else {
    println(false)
}
```

If it is a web link you need to use NSURL(string:). fileUrlWithPath it is only for local resources.

```
if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string: "http://a1993.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/101/Music/b7/b3/e0/mzm.ooahqslp.aac.p.m4‌​") {
    println(true)
} else {
    println(false)
}
```