# How playing 3gpp file on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

```
            var player:AVAudioPlayer

            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundFileURL, fileTypeHint: AVFileType3GPP)

            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
```

catch with error

> Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003334207 "(null)"

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the following StackOverflow question since I believe the answer is given there :)

[AVAudioPlayer with external URL to *.m4p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605846/avaudioplayer-with-external-url-to-m4p)

Comment: all the same catch Code=2003334207